# How to get summarize output basis on particular column without repetition of that column?

Tags: sql-server, summarization

I have four different tables in SQL Server for which I'm using left join & inner join to get summarized output on basis of particular column of that table, but I want in output that column should not be repeated. My output is not as expected.

For e.g. A,B,C,D these are the my table where I'm using left join & inner join but I got an output as shown here:

| Acc_no | VPN | VPN_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | abc@ybl | 4 |
| 12345678 | bcd@ybl | 4 |
| 12345678 | cde@ybl | 4 |
| 12345678 | def@ybl | 4 |

But I want output to look like this - as one `Acc_no` has 4 vpn's that count is 4:

| Acc_no | VPN | VPN_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | abc@ybl | 4 |
|  | bcd@ybl |  |
|  | cde@ybl |  |
|  | def@ybl |  |

How to get this output in SQL Server please? Can anyone help me with  this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use LAG function to check previous value and NULL the current one if they are the same

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76055872/how-to-get-summarize-output-basis-on-particular-field-without-repetition-of-that#comment134134740_76055872) one method would be to use `LAG` to check the prior value. To avoid repetition of the `OVER` clause I use the `WINDOW` clause here, however, if you aren't on 2022+ you'll need to explicitly define the `OVER` clause for each `LAG` function.

```sql
SELECT CASE V.Acc_no WHEN LAG(V.Acc_no) OVER Prev THEN NULL ELSE V.Acc_no END AS Acc_no,
       CASE V.VPN WHEN LAG(V.VPN) OVER Prev THEN NULL ELSE V.VPN END AS VPN,
       CASE V.VPN_Count WHEN LAG(V.VPN_Count) OVER Prev THEN NULL ELSE V.VPN_Count END AS VPN_Count
FROM (VALUES(12345678,'abc@ybl',4),
            (12345678,'bcd@ybl',4),
            (12345678,'cde@ybl',4),
            (12345678,'def@ybl',4))V(Acc_no,VPN,VPN_Count)
WINDOW Prev AS (PARTITION BY Acc_no ORDER BY VPN, VPN_Count);
```

[db<<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JngyQa1X)